# "I was approached by what looked like a group of priests"

Tags: pronouns, construction

Is there a name for the construction in bold in the following sentences?

- I was approached by **what looked like a group of priests**.
- This is the beginning of **what might be a new era of science**!
- I'm sorry I'm late. I was held up for two hours at **what should have been a 30-minute meeting**.

Comment: What do you see as being the distinctive features of these sentences, and what sentences wouldn't be included? Is it the relative/wh-clause with some degree of doubt or uncertainty?

Comment: Yes. They are noun phrases.

Comment: More specifically, they are NPs in fused relative constructions.

Comment: @chocojunkie Are you clear now that in each of your examples, the _what_  expression is  a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction?

Answer (score 6):

I would consider all of these [nominal relative clauses](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/483/noun-clauses) that are acting as [prepositional objects](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/511/objects-of-prepositions).

> Nominal relative clauses are used as objects, subjects, or complements for the main clause and they act as a noun or a noun phrase. As a result, they are regarded as noun clauses or nominal clauses.

A defined by [University College London](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/glossary/n.htm#:%7E:text=A%20type%20of%20relative%20clause,the%20thing%20which%20I%20want%22.), a nominal relative clause is

> A type of relative clause that does not have a Head word. The man who I know contains a standard relative clause with a Head noun man. In what I want is a new car, what I want is a nominal relative clause, which may be paraphrased as "the thing which I want". They are also known as independent relative clauses.

Therefore, in the sentence

> I was approached by what looked like a group of priests,

the nominal relative clause is "what looked like a group of priests", which is also in this case a complement.

This could easily be converted into the subject of the sentence by writing

> What looked like a group of priests approached me.

It would remain a nominal relative clause.

Comment: Please add the relevant material from your sources, Melissa. / 'Wh-clauses' and  'prepositional complements' are probably the preferred terms nowadays.

Comment: S Granath — 'According to their descriptions, prepositions may take noun phrases, -ing participle clauses and wh-clauses as their complements' [University of Birmingham]

Comment: Sorry, Edwin, I mainly work with EFL users. It might take me a bit to get used to native-level explanations.

Comment: @MelissaM. Yes, the _what_ expressions are complements of a preposition, though they are not actually clauses but noun phrases in fused relative constructions. The fusion involves "what", which is understood as "that which".

Answer (score 5):

> [1] *I was approached by* [*what looked like a group of priests*].
>
> [2] *This is the beginning of* [*what might be a new era of science*]!
>
> [3] *I'm sorry I'm late. I was held up for two hours at* [*what should have*
> *been a 30-minute meeting*].

In each case, the bracketed constituent consist of a noun phrase in a fused relative construction.

The fusion involves the noun phrase "what", which serves simultaneously as head of the NP and the relativised element in a relative clause functioning as a modifier within the NP.

In simple terms, fused "what" may be understood as "that which", so [1], for example, may be understood as:

> *I was approached by that which looked like a group of priests*.